# Mapping Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have 2 Entities: Technologie and Competence

Each competence can have 1 or more Techno

so i have generate the classes by Hibernate

and he gave me 3 classes Model

```
Technologie
Competence
TechnologieId
```

and now i'm confused about how to add a technologie

and what is the point of `TechnoligieId` ?

Technologie.java

```
public class Technologie implements java.io.Serializable {

    private TechnologieId id;
    private Competence competence;
    private String libelleTechnologie;
}
```

TechnologieId.java

```
public class TechnologieId implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int idCompetence;
    private int idTechnologie;
}
```

Technologie.hbm.xml

```
 <class name="com.model.Technologie" table="technologie" catalog="gestioncollaborateur">
        <composite-id name="id" class="com.model.TechnologieId">
            <key-property name="idCompetence" type="int">
                <column name="idCompetence" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="idTechnologie" type="int">
                <column name="idTechnologie" />
            </key-property>
        </composite-id>
        <many-to-one name="competence" class="com.model.Competence" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
            <column name="idCompetence" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="libelleTechnologie" type="string">
            <column name="libelleTechnologie" length="254" />
        </property>
    </class>
```

Comment: You have a third class/table because it uses a n:n mapping. Now every competence can have many technology and every technology can have multiple competences (which makes sense to me)

Comment: Yes but how can i add a new technologie, do i need to create new technologieid every time i need to create new technologie

Comment: Have you tried to add a new technologie? What have you tried, what has worked, and what hasn't?

Comment: No, i just need to know if i have to create a class Dao and Service for TechnologieId

Comment: can you post the table definitions, did you generate the model using Hibernate tools?

Comment: Apart from ManyToOne from the Technology side? So, one Competence can contain multiple Technologies. What about Technologies? Can they contain Many Competencies ? Basically, what i am asking is is it a ManyToMany relationship?

Comment: Yes in used Hibernate tools to generate hbm.xml and classe model

Answer (score 0):

If the relationship is mentioned correctly in the question. Then why dont you do something like this?

```
public class Technologie implements java.io.Serializable {

private id;
private Competence competence;
private String libelleTechnologie;


@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="<yourForeign Key for Competence>")
public Competence getCompetence() {
    return competence;
}
}
```

And the Competence Class such as.

```
public class Competence implements java.io.Serializable {

private id;
private List<Technologie> technologies;


@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(mappedBy = "<name of the property of Competence in Technology class>")
public List<Technologies> getTechnologies() {
    return technologies;
}
}
```

Also, this is if the Technology is the managing side of the relationship. Basically, what it means is you will do a save / update on the Technologie primarily which will handle the relationship.

If you do want the **@OneToMany side as the managing side. you would have to add the insertable=false, updatable=false** attributes in the @JoinColumn annotation for the the getTechnologies method.